# Database of bicycle stations in Minato (Tokyo)

Tags: data-request, geospatial, public-transport, japan, bikesharing

Minato (a ward within Tokyo) has started a bicycle sharing service called 港区自転車シェアリング.

Where can I find a database of all sharing stations of this service?

Requirements:

- Latitude
- Longitude

Bonus:

- Number of slots
- Real-time number of empty slots, broken slots
- Altitude

Answer (score 2):

The service's map shows a map of stations: http://docomo-cycle.jp/minato/map/

Reading the JavaScript source code leads to a JSON file which contains the data with location names in Japanese:

http://docomo-cycle.jp/minato/system/data/portnavi.json

The location names in English are found by prepending 'en' in front of portnavi.json:

http://docomo-cycle.jp/minato/system/data/enportnavi.json

Each participating ward uses the same URL syntax. Replace 'minato' with the other ward(s) name for their information.

The wards are:
chiyoda
yokohama
sendai

This data is not always up-to-date, though, some stations are missing.

Comment: I have to upvote this for the effort Nicolas made reading thru a Japanese website. I double check and found that the other wards participating use the same web url syntax - http://docomo-cycle.jp/<ward name>/system/data/portnavi.json